# How to import Access data to SQLite with ODBC into an existing table, not a new one?

Tags: sqlite, ms-access, import, odbc

I want to import data (not structure) from Access to SQLite via ODBC
and it works, but there is one point that is annoying:

I don't want to create a new table automatically - I want to import data into my existing table and I get the following error:

```
ODBC--call failed
table "x" already exists(1)(#1)
```

I want to find a way to avoid creating new table in sqlite.

I have also tried another solution for importing my data from Access to SQLite via csv. However, my encoding is utf-8 but it shows data as question marks!

Comment: Please share your code doing the import. If you're not importing using code, consider asking this on [su]. Stack Overflow is for programming problems.

Comment: thanks dear Erik for revising my question and about about your question I've just use access wizard-Right click on table -choose export -ODBC Database,..

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to move data around using Access.

When appending data to ODBC tables, I recommend the following steps:

1. Create a linked table to the ODBC table you want to import to in Access using Import -> ODBC database
2. Use an append query to move the data from the local table to the ODBC table
3. (optional) Remove the linked table.

Alternatively, Access can directly run append queries to ODBC data sources without creating linked tables, but this requires some SQL knowledge. Syntax is the following:

```
INSERT INTO [ODBC;MyDSNOrConnectionString].[MyRemoteTable] (Field1, Field2, FieldN)
SELECT Field1, Field2, FieldN
FROM MyLocalTable
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way of exporting Access table records into an exisitng ODBC table with Adobe connection, if the tables on both side have the same name and the same structure and if the table structure is stored in a system table.

```
    Dim Str_Sql As String
    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim myDSN As String
    Dim UserName As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim Rs_Tabl As DAO.Recordset
    Dim Rs_TablStru As DAO.Recordset

    myDSN = ...
    UserName = ...
    Password = ...

    Conn.Open "dsn=" & myDSN & ";uid=" & UserName & ";pwd=" & Password

    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn
    Set Rs_Tabl = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(TablName)
    Set Rs_TablStru = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from Systable where TableName=TableName order by ColumnOrder")

    Str_Sql = "truncate table TableName"

    Conn.Execute (Str_Sql)

    Str_Sql = "insert into TableName values ('"

    Do Until Rs_Tabl.EOF

        Str_Sql = "insert into TableName values ('"

        Rs_TablStru.MoveFirst

        Do Until Rs_TablStru.EOF

            Str_Sql = Str_Sql & Rs_Tabl.Fields(Rs_TablStru.Fields("AAA")) & "','"

            Rs_TablStru.MoveNext
        Loop

        Str_Sql = Mid(Str_Sql, 1, Len(Str_Sql) - 2) & ")"

        Debug.Print Str_Sql
        Conn.Execute (Str_Sql)

        Rs_Tabl.MoveNext
    Loop

    Rs_Tabl.Close
    Rs_TablStru.Close
    Set Rs_Tabl = Nothing
    Set Rs_TablStru = Nothing
    Conn.Close
```

*AAA:A column from system table that stores column names from all tables.