# Clone table from one database to another (Access, ODBC and C#)

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, odbc

Using Microsoft Access with ODBC and C#. The following query correctly clones a table in the same database (though with primary key information stripped):

```
SELECT * INTO [NewTable] FROM [ExistingTable] WHERE 1=0;
```

To create a blank database the following works:

```
// P/Invoke ODBCCP32.DLL::SQLConfigDataSource
enum RequestFlags : Int16
{
    // Comments from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlconfigdatasource-function
    ODBC_ADD_DSN = 1,               // Add a new user data source
    ODBC_CONFIG_DSN = 2,            // Configure (modify) an existing user data source
    ODBC_REMOVE_DSN = 3,            // Remove an existing user data source
    ODBC_ADD_SYS_DSN = 4,           // Add a new system data source
    ODBC_CONFIG_SYS_DSN = 5,        // Modify an existing system data source
    ODBC_REMOVE_SYS_DSN = 6,        // Remove an existing system data source
    ODBC_REMOVE_DEFAULT_DSN = 7     // Remove default data source specification section from system information
}

[DllImport("ODBCCP32.DLL",CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool SQLConfigDataSource(UInt32 hwndParent, RequestFlags fRequest, string lpszDriver, string lpszAttributes);

// ...
string driver32 = "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)";            // 32-bit
string driver64 = "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)";   // 64-bit
string command = "CREATE_DB=C:\Tmp\MyCoolDB.mdb";
bool dbCreated = SQLConfigDataSource(0, RequestFlags.ODBC_ADD_DSN, driver32, command);
```

How do you copy a table from one database to another, ideally in raw SQL or using ODBCCP32.DLL?

Comment: Can the source db connect directly to the destination db in some way? If yes, you can conenct them up (e.g. SQLServer can link to an Access DB over remote link/become an odbc client of the access db) and run your SELECT INTO. If not, you might have to trip via C# - select data into the client, then insert to the other. Lots of tools exist for this, why are you reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Access can insert natively into any ODBC database, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52496516/7296893). I'd recommend not using extern for anything that  can be done with System.Data.Odbc, but that's up to you.

Comment: @CaiusJard: Not trying to re-invent, but to discover that elusive wheel ! I need to do this programmatically in .NET (primarily C#, but the codebase uses some VB.NET as well).